# Pass value to another view django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I searched a lot but I didn't find a working solution and I even don't know the mechanism that makes redirect between two view possible.
I use

```
return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('message-inbox', args=(),kwargs={}));
```

It works correctly.But I want to pass some values to message-inbox's View and retrieve them in that View.I thought about passing them to request object but I don't know if this is possible and also I don't know how I can do somethings like that.
I would be appreciate for any bit of help.

Comment: Create a url with the necessary kwargs, then pass them in the redirect view in the kwargs dic.
Mind though that this is for get requests so sensitive data is exposed, if you need a different approach just assign more sensitive data to the user session and retrieve it from there.
In case you are dealing with high sensitive data you could opt for a different approach like temporarily storing data to a DB and retrieving it in the necessary views.
Url dispatching is pretty much covered in the official django documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/) is for.

In your source view:

```
request.session['my_key'] = my_value
```

And in your inbox view:

```
my_value = request.session['my_key']
```

Of course, if they're just small integers or strings, you could pass them in the URL parameters like any other view.

Comment: This is one of the top indexed pages and session link has gone 404. Please update